# is it possible to achieve drag and drop with bootstrap responsive css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

We are creating dynamic application(layout) using angular , jQuery, kendo, bootstrap etc, which consist of container and content boxes. My requirement is to achieve to drag and drop(which means anything can placed anywhere) with bootstrap responsive css.

Anyone help me in static or dynamic way to example. If you guys need more elaborate manner. please let me know. Thank in advance.

Comment: Predicting what a user will do is hard, if not nigh impossible. You're best bet is to create a great journey for the end user, showing them how YOU want them to use it.

Comment: What is the specific question, because to me it sound like your asking us to create your website for you.

Comment: @George - I just asking possible ways are there or not. If there any example. please I modified my question also.

Comment: [gridstack.js](https://troolee.github.io/gridstack.js/) is a very nice jQuery plugin used for drag-and-drop layouts. There are lots of samples and documentation available [here](https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js)

Answer (score 0):

This library will do exactly what you want.
https://rosspi.github.io/gridstrap.js/
It will maintain the responsiveness of bootstrap.